# Setting "Write member attribute" in ACL on Active Directory object with powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, acl, active-directory-group

I would like to programatically allow a given security principal (user or group) in AD to have write permission to the `member` attribute on an AD group.

I'm assuming it would be of the form:

```
$GroupObject = Get-ADGroup $group
$ACL = Get-ACL AD:$GroupObject
$ACE = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.ActiveDirectoryAccessRule (
    $manager,
    ...
)
$ACL.AddAccessRule($ACE)
Set-ACL -Path AD:$GroupObject -AclObject $ACL
```

What I'm unable to find is documentation on what else needs to go in the `...` to make this work. Even diving doing it manually and inspecting the resultant ACL Objects is proving difficult!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd use this constructor for `ActiveDirectoryAccessRule`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cawwkf0x(v=vs.110).aspx

It should look something like this:

```
$ACE = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryAccessRule(
    $manager.SID,
    [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryRights]::WriteProperty,
    [System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::Allow,
    "bf9679c0-0de6-11d0-a285-00aa003049e2",
    [DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectorySecurityInheritance]::All
)
```

Note that you need to pass the SID of the user (`$manager.SID`).

The mysterious GUID is the GUID of the `member` attribute. You can find that by looking at the Microsoft documentation for the attributes. This is the page for `member`, where you can find the "System-Id-Guid": https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677097(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: As a bit of an aside, while I have the `ActiveDirectory` module loaded in PowerShell, it's now complaining:

`New-Object : Cannot find type [System.Security.AccessControl.ActiveDirectoryAccessRule]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded`.

I have tried `add-type -AssemblyName System.DirectoryServices` to no avail.

Comment: Oh, I didn't even notice the differences in the types, but I see now that I used `System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryAccessRule`, which is different than what you used. Try that. I tested my code with a group in our domain and it worked.

Comment: Thanks - that's got it